# How to load PNG image with circle on SVG?

Tags: svg

I want to create a circle which contain an image. I have tried the below code. But it's not working. Please any one help us what I am doing wrong.

```
<circle id="selectorGrip_rotate" fill="url(#img1)" r="4" stroke="#22C" stroke-width="2" style="cursor:url(images/rotate.png) 12 12, auto;" cx="437.7578125" cy="103.61328125">
<image id="img1" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="imgUrl">
```

Comment: Easier if you create an image and then clip it to a circle. If you really want a circle element with an image in it though you'll need to create a pattern with the image in it and then fill the circle with the pattern.

Comment: In addition to Robert's comment, you aren't closing either your `circle` or `image` tags.

Comment: Any possible create include the image with in  circle with out using pattern?

Comment: Yes. See Robert's first suggestion. Apply a circular `<clipPath>` to the image.